# Parsing XML and populating into Map

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have xml as below.

```
<Employees>
      <Employee id="1">Chuck</Employee>
      <Employee id="2">Al</Employee>
      <Employee id="3">Kiran</Employee>
</Employees>
```

XML contains huge number of employees.I have mentioned only for simplification.

What is the best way to parse this xml and populate into a map? Map should contain id and name pairs.

Please provide code for better understanding.

Comment: Use jdom and iterate over all employee entries adding into a `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: What have you tried? do you know the difference between SAX, DOM, XPATH, ect... please search stackoverflow before posting. I think this question has been answered about 1000 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply map this using Xstream.

```
XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
xStream.alias("Employees", Employees.class);
xStream.registerConverter(new MapEntryConverter());
employeesMap = (Map<String, String>) xStream.fromXML(queryXML);
```

Create a converter which unmarshall XML to Map object

```
private static class MapEntryConverter implements Converter {
        public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
            return clazz.equals(Employees.class);
        }

        public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
            AbstractMap<String, String> map = (AbstractMap<String, String>) value;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                writer.startNode(entry.getKey().toString());
                writer.setValue(entry.getValue().toString());
                writer.endNode();
            }
        }

        public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            while (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
                reader.moveDown();
                map.put(reader.getAttribute(1), reader.getValue());
                reader.moveUp();
            }
            return map;
        }
    }
```

Create Employees and Employee classes as below.

```
private class Employees{
        List<Employee> employees;
    }
    private class Employee{
        private String id;
        private String value;
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 4):

The [XStream answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11886299/383861) seems like a lot of code.  You could do something like the following with the StAX APIs in the JDK/JRE:

```
package forum11871952;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("src/forum11871952/input.xml"));
        xsr.nextTag(); // advance to Employees tag
        xsr.nextTag(); // advance to first Employer element
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        while(xsr.getLocalName().equals("Employee")) {
            map.put(xsr.getAttributeValue("", "id"), xsr.getElementText());
            xsr.nextTag(); // advance to next Employer element
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a library such as XStream. `List<Employee>` suits better than a `Map` here.

Comment: `List` is better than a `Map` if OP doesn't care about lookup times.

Comment: how about `Set` over both `List` or `Map`

Comment: My requirement is to set in Map